# Why the light contrast of a set $\mathcal{E}$ of VCRG produced by an encryption scheme for a binary image B is defined as follows

Tags: encryption, visual-cryptography

In the paper [“Image encryption by multiple random grids”](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220603473_Image_encryption_by_multiple_random_grids), Shyong Jian Shyu, 42(7):1582-1596,· July 2009, the light contrast of a set $\mathcal{E}$ of VCRG produced by an
encryption scheme for a binary image B is defined as
$$c(\mathcal{E})=\frac{\mathcal{T}(S[B(0)])-\mathcal{T}(S[B(1)])}{1+\mathcal{T}(S[B(1)])}$$

My question is : denominator taken as $1+\mathcal{T}(S[B(1)])$ why?